# Can you construct csrf from request object - csrf constructor exception?

Tags: python, django

I am following an example of user registration and my code looks like this

```
from django.views.decorators import  csrf
def register_user(request):
    args={}
    args.update(csrf(request)) #---->Crashes here
    args["form"] = UserCreationForm()
    return render_to_response("register.html",args)
```

I get an exception at the statement

```
args.update(csrf(request))
```

stating that the

```
module object is not callable.
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your code, you need `django.template.context_processors.csrf()`, not `django.views.decorators.csrf`. This puts the csrf token in the template context.

The recommended way is to use `render` instead of `render_to_response`. This will run all configured [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext), including the `csrf` context processor.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def register_user(request):
    args = {}
    args["form"] = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, "register.html", args)
```

This is what allows you to use the `{% csrf_token %}` template tag in your templates.

You still need to use either the `CsrfViewMiddleware` (recommended) or `csrf_protect` decorator to actually protect your views.

Answer (score 2):

There are two way to CSRF protect your django websites :

## 1 - Using the middleware, the simplest way :

The `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` automatically adds a CSRF token to the context.

This middleware is enabled by default in your `settings.py` file and you can directly use this token in your template.

**With this solution you have nothing to do but using the {% csrf_token %} tag in your template as bellow.**

## 2 - Using the `csrf_protect` decorator :

If you deactivate the middleware (which is not recommended), you can still use the `csrf_protect` decorator (It seems it's the solution you're trying, but not with its correct import as Danielle pointed out).

But your problem seems to be that you don't use it as you should.

It's a **decorator**, i-e a function that returns a modified version of a function passed as parameter. Here you're passing it a request object.

With Python, you canuse a decorator this way :

```
@decorator
def function([...]):
    [...]
```

So your view should look like :

```
@csrf_token
def your_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Your view code
```

## Using the `{% csrf_token %}` tag :

After using one of these solutions, you can directly use the `{% csrf_token %}` tag in your template since the csrf token should be in your context at template rendering (thanks to either the middleware or the `csrf_protect` decorator) :

```
<form>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is more about CSRF protections with Django :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/

and here is more about decorators with Python :

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators

Comment: would i need to pass the CSRF value from my view to my template ?

Comment: No, you just need the `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` middleware (enable by default),

Comment: @JamesFranco To make it short. You could use decorators. But you could directly use this tag in your template without having anything to add in your view (assuming you didn't remove the middleware from your `settings.py`).

Comment: Looks like you do need to create a csrf token in the view. Otherwise you will get an invalid csrf token on a post from the template. @Knbk answer did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google shows that the correct import for the csrf decorator is

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
```

My guess (I don't have django available to test) is that you're importing something else, although it's probably a non callable module :)

Comment: I think you're using decorators incorrectly - check out the docs here for an example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#module-django.views.decorators.csrf